# Installing cairo for python 3.3 on redhat 6

Tags: python-3.x, redhat, cairo, pycairo, rhel6

I am trying to install pycairo 1.10 for Python 3.3 on redhat 6. There are no packages in the official repo, and when I try building it myself it says glibc is out of date. I have the latest glibc from the official the repo, and am somewhat hesitant to go on updating it through other means. Are there any other packages that can help, or is there some way to get this working with an older version (we have tried back to cairo 1.8).

Answer (score 0):

redhat 6 is clearly out of date. Of course it can be done bringing rh6 up to date with downloading and compiling your own 3.x kernel with all what's needed to meet the requirments for pycairo 1.10....
BUT it would be easier and nicer to install a more modern Linux Distribution which goes nicely with an old computer. Linux Mint 16 (Petra) provides a distro with replaxed requirments and window managers in i386 mode.

I don't see any meaning in trying to get up to date code on such an old os version running. Every replacement hardware you can get hold on ebay will do better than that.

cheers,
Christian